# str.strip() strange behavior

Tags: python, string

```
>>> t1 = "abcd.org.gz"
>>> t1
'abcd.org.gz'
>>> t1.strip("g")
'abcd.org.gz'
>>> t1.strip("gz")
'abcd.org.'
>>> t1.strip(".gz")
'abcd.or'
```

Why is the `'g'` of `'.org'` gone?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`strip(".gz")` removes any of the characters `.`, `g` and `z` from the beginning and end of the string.

Answer (score 9):

[`x.strip(y)` will remove all characters that appear in `y` from the beginning and end of `x`.](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#str.strip)

That means

```
'foo42'.strip('1234567890') == 'foo'
```

becuase `'4'` and `'2'` both appear in `'1234567890'`.

---

Use [`os.path.splitext`](http://docs.python.org/library/os.path.html) if you want to remove the file extension.

```
>>> import os.path
>>> t1 = "abcd.org.gz"
>>> os.path.splitext(t1)
('abcd.org', '.gz')
```

Comment: `'abcd.org.gz'.strip('.gzor')` produces `'abcd'` -- surprisingly enough the docstring isn't too helpful unless you notice the `[]` in the `S.strip([chars])` and remember that a string is just a sequence of characters.

Good explanation, and good alternative

Comment: @Wayne: doesn't the `[]` mean "optional" in the doc?

Comment: it might, I have no idea - but if it does, I'd consider that a bug in the documentation.

Comment: @Wayne: It's used as "optional" everywhere e.g. http://docs.python.org/py3k/library/functions.html#range.

Comment: I guess that's why I didn't notice it as suggesting a collection at first! That means the docstring for strip is ambiguous and could use some clearer wording. While the name 'chars' is suggestive, the docstring isn't clear that it uses the collection in any order from front and back - at least not to me.

Comment: @WayneWerner but it is optional - if you leave the parameter off, it defaults to a list of whitespace characters.

Answer (score 5):

In **Python 3.9**, there are two new string methods `.removeprefix()` and `.removesuffix()` to remove the beginning or end of a string, respectively. Thankfully this time, the method names make it aptly clear what these methods are supposed to perform.

```
>>> print (sys.version)
3.9.0 
>>> t1 = "abcd.org.gz"
>>> t1.removesuffix('gz')
'abcd.org.'
>>> t1
'abcd.org.gz'
>>> t1.removesuffix('gz').removesuffix('.gz')
'abcd.org.'     # No unexpected effect from last removesuffix call
```

Answer (score 1):

The argument given to `strip` is a set of characters to be removed, not a substring.  [From the docs](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#str.strip):

> The chars argument is a string specifying the set of characters to be removed.

Answer (score 1):

as far as I know strip removes from the beginning or end of a string only. If you want to remove from the whole string use replace.