# Strange behaviour of Python strip function

Tags: python, string, strip

I have this code:

```
st = '55000.0'
st = st.strip('.0')
print st
```

I expected it to print `55000`, but instead it prints `55`.
I thought perhaps the `.` in the argument might need to be escaped (like in a regular expression); so I also tried `st = st.strip('\.0')`, but the result is the same.

Why are all the zeros removed from the input? Why doesn't it stop after removing the `.0`?

Comment: could just use `int(round(float(st)))`

Comment: +1 to @KennyTM - quick description is that `strip()` removes any characters specified in its argument from the beginning and end of a string, and returns a new string without those characters.

Comment: In python 3.9, you can do `st = st.removesuffix('.0')`. More on this: 
https://stackoverflow.com/a/64295844/1465553

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You've misunderstood strip() - it removes **any** of the specified characters from both ends; there is no regex support here.

You're asking it to strip both `.` and `0` off both ends, so it does - and gets left with `55`.

See the [official String class docs](http://docs.python.org/library/string.html#string.strip) for details.

Answer (score 5):

See the documentation on [`str.strip`](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#str.strip), the important part being:

The *chars* argument is not a prefix or suffix; rather, all combinations of its values are stripped:

```
>>> '   spacious   '.strip()  
'spacious'  
>>> 'www.example.com'.strip('cmowz.')  
'example'
```

Comment: and same rule apply with `rstrip` ?

Answer (score 5):

Because you're telling it to strip all periods and 0s, so it keeps going up to the first non-period, non-0 character.

Strip uses a list of characters, not a specific configuration of them.

Try something like this instead:

```
st.partition('.')[0]
```

Comment: This works fine.  I would use rpartition() though since I think of it as stripping off the righthand side.

Comment: Sure, depends on what you expect to see in the string. If it's a normal decimal number either would work.

Comment: +1: the best workaround for the specific situation.

Answer (score 2):

Because [that's what `strip` does](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=strip#str.strip):

> The chars argument is not a prefix or suffix; rather, all combinations of its values are stripped

Answer (score 2):

Because the argument to `strip` is the *set* of characters to be removed, not the *string* to be removed. In other words. It removes each character from the ends of that string that are anywhere in the set, until it encounters a character not in that set.

Answer (score 1):

`strip` works on individual characters. You told it to strip all '.' and '0' characters, and that's what it did.

Answer (score 1):

Refer to http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#string-formatting

The [chars] arguments lists the SET of characters that must be removed from the string!

To get the desired result of 5500, use `a.split('.0')[0]`